# Apache Beam IllegalArgumentException on Google Dataflow with message `Not expecting a splittable ParDoSingle: should have been overridden`

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to write a pipeline which periodically checks a Google Storage bucket for new `.gz` files which are actually compressed `.csv` files. Then it writes those records to a BigQuery table. The following code was working in batch mode before I added the `.watchForNewFiles(...)` and `.withMethod(STREAMING_INSERTS)` parts. I am expecting it to run in streaming mode with those changes. However I am getting an exception that I can't find anything related on the web. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       

    DataflowDfpOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
            //.withValidation()
            .as(DataflowDfpOptions.class);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    log.info("DFP data transfer from GS to BQ has started.");

    pipeline.apply("ReadFromStorage", TextIO.read()
            .from("gs://my-bucket/my-folder/*.gz")
            .withCompression(Compression.GZIP)
            .watchForNewFiles(
                    // Check for new files every 30 seconds
                    Duration.standardSeconds(30),
                    // Never stop checking for new files
                    Watch.Growth.never()
            )
    )
            .apply("TransformToTableRow", ParDo.of(new TableRowConverterFn()))
            .apply("WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .to(options.getTableId())
                    .withMethod(STREAMING_INSERTS)
                    .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND)
                    .withSchema(TableSchema)); //todo: use withJsonScheme(String json) method instead

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();

    log.info("DFP data transfer from GS to BQ is finished in {} seconds.", sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}

/**
 * Creates a TableRow from a CSV line
 */
private static class TableRowConverterFn extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

        String[] split = c.element().split(",");

        //Ignore the header line
        //Since this is going to be run in parallel, we can't guarantee that the first line passed to this method will be the header
        if (split[0].equals("Time")) {
            log.info("Skipped header");
            return;
        }

        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            TableFieldSchema col = TableSchema.getFields().get(i);

            //String is the most common type, putting it in the first if clause for a little bit optimization.
            if (col.getType().equals("STRING")) {
                row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
            } else if (col.getType().equals("INTEGER")) {
                row.set(col.getName(), Long.valueOf(split[i]));
            } else if (col.getType().equals("BOOLEAN")) {
                row.set(col.getName(), Boolean.valueOf(split[i]));
            } else if (col.getType().equals("FLOAT")) {
                row.set(col.getName(), Float.valueOf(split[i]));
            } else {
                //Simply try to write it as a String if
                //todo: Consider other BQ data types.
                row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
            }
        }
        c.output(row);
    }
}
```

And the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not expecting a splittable ParDoSingle: should have been overridden
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_google_cloud_dataflow_java.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory$PayloadTranslator.payloadForParDoSingle(PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory$PayloadTranslator.translate(PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory.java:145)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:206)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.SdkComponents.registerPTransform(SdkComponents.java:86)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineTranslation$1.visitPrimitiveTransform(PipelineTranslation.java:87)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:668)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:458)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineTranslation.toProto(PipelineTranslation.java:59)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:165)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:684)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
    at com.diply.data.App.main(App.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my command to publish the job on Dataflow:

```
clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.my.project.App "-Dexec.args=--runner=DataflowRunner --tempLocation=gs://my-bucket/tmp --tableId=Temp.TestTable --project=my-project --jobName=dataflow-dfp-streaming" -Pdataflow-runner
```

I use apache beam version `2.5.0`. Here is the relevant section from my `pom.xml`.

```
 <properties>
   <beam.version>2.5.0</beam.version>
   <bigquery.version>v2-rev374-1.23.0</bigquery.version>
   <google-clients.version>1.23.0</google-clients.version>
   ...
 </properties>
```

Comment: What version of dataflow are you using ? I just ran your code without errors in 2.5.0
Can you also provide us with the command line arguments through which you run your DataflowRunner ?

Comment: @ThehBarTender I edited the question and added the details you asked for. Thanks.

Comment: Do you also get this error with a DirectRunner ? Here's the code I'm running to test your issue https://pastebin.com/RmjcsYLz, are you able to run it without errors with your pom ? If not, could you try with this pom https://pastebin.com/BKCZVnqX and tell me what happens ?

Comment: @ThehBarTender Neither worked. Here is my pom. https://pastebin.com/AFA5EbZL. With direct-runner I don't get any errors, it can successfully watch the new files but it doesn't write data to the BQ. So, it doesn't work as expected in local mode either.

Comment: For your original question, see my answer below. If an issue persists with BigQuery, consider opening a separate StackOverflow question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the code with Dataflow 2.4.0 gives a more explicit error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DataflowRunner does not currently support splittable DoFn`

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896489/10054105) suggests that this is supported since 2.2.0. This is indeed the case, and following [this remark](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/beam-user/201803.mbox/%3CCAFmTo48==Zxy43zrGaPKyu61Zog4TC=B=Db7GtVNB5GTOS7ZVQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) **you need to add the `--streaming` option in your `Dexec.args` to force it into streaming mode**.

I tested it with [the code I supplied in the comments](https://pastebin.com/RmjcsYLz) with both [your pom](https://pastebin.com/AFA5EbZL) and [mine](https://pastebin.com/BKCZVnqX) and both 1. produce your error without `--streaming` 2. run fine with `--streaming`

You might want to open a github beam issue since this behavior is not documented anywhere offically as far as I know.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on Dataflow but not locally. When I run it locally, I don't get any exception or error but the last part of the pipeline that writes to the BQ does not work.