# reading files and folders in order with apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have a folder structure of the type `year/month/day/hour/*`, and I'd like the beam to read this as an unbounded source in chronological order. Specifically, this means reading in all the files in the first hour on record and adding their contents for processing. Then, add the file contents of the next hour for processing, up until the current time where it waits for new files to arrive in the latest `year/month/day/hour` folder.

Is it possible to do this with apache beam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I would do is to add timestamps to each element according to the file path. As a test I used the following example.

First of all, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544945/6121516), you can use `FileIO` to match continuously a file pattern. This will help as, per your use case, once you have finished with the backfill you want to keep reading new arriving files within the same job. In this case I provide `gs://BUCKET_NAME/data/**` because my files will be like `gs://BUCKET_NAME/data/year/month/day/hour/filename.extension`:

```java
p
    .apply(FileIO.match()
    .filepattern(inputPath)
    .continuously(
        // Check for new files every minute
        Duration.standardMinutes(1),
        // Never stop checking for new files
        Watch.Growth.<String>never()))
    .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
```

Watch frequency and timeout can be adjusted at will.

Then, in the next step we'll receive the matched file. I will use `ReadableFile.getMetadata().resourceId()` to get the full path and split it by `"/"` to build the corresponding timestamp. I round it to the hour and do not account for timezone correction here. With `readFullyAsUTF8String` we'll read the whole file (be careful if the whole file does not fit into memory, it is recommended to shard your input if needed) and split it into lines. With `ProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp` we'll emit downstream a KV of filename and line (the filename is not needed anymore but it will help to see where each file comes from) and the timestamp derived from the path. Note that we're shifting timestamps "back in time" so this can mess up with the watermark heuristics and you will get a message such as:

> Cannot output with timestamp 2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z. Output timestamps must be no earlier than the timestamp of the current input (2019-06-05T15:41:29.645Z) minus the allowed skew (0 milliseconds). See the DoFn#getAllowedTimestampSkew() Javadoc for details on changing the allowed skew.

To overcome this I set `getAllowedTimestampSkew` to `Long.MAX_VALUE` but take into account that this is deprecated. ParDo code:

```java
.apply("Add Timestamps", ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public Duration getAllowedTimestampSkew() {
        return new Duration(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        ReadableFile file = c.element();
        String fileName = file.getMetadata().resourceId().toString();
        String lines[];

        String[] dateFields = fileName.split("/");
        Integer numElements = dateFields.length;

        String hour = dateFields[numElements - 2];
        String day = dateFields[numElements - 3];
        String month = dateFields[numElements - 4];
        String year = dateFields[numElements - 5];

        String ts = String.format("%s-%s-%s %s:00:00", year, month, day, hour);
        Log.info(ts);

        try{
            lines = file.readFullyAsUTF8String().split("\n");

            for (String line : lines) {
                c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(fileName, line), new Instant(dateTimeFormat.parseMillis(ts)));
            }
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            Log.info("failed");
        }
    }}))
```

Finally, I window into 1-hour `FixedWindows` and log the results:

```java
.apply(Window
    .<KV<String,String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1)))
    .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
    .discardingFiredPanes()
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO))
.apply("Log results", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, Void>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window) {
        String file = c.element().getKey();
        String value = c.element().getValue();
        String eventTime = c.timestamp().toString();

        String logString = String.format("File=%s, Line=%s, Event Time=%s, Window=%s", file, value, eventTime, window.toString());
        Log.info(logString);
    }
}));
```

For me it worked with `.withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)` but depending on the order you might need to set it. Keep in mind that a value too high will cause windows to be open for longer and use more persistent storage.

I set the `$BUCKET` and `$PROJECT` variables and I just upload two files:

```sh
gsutil cp file1 gs://$BUCKET/data/2019/03/17/00/
gsutil cp file2 gs://$BUCKET/data/2019/03/18/22/
```

And run the job with:

```sh
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile -e exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.dataflow.samples.ChronologicalOrder \
      -Dexec.args="--project=$PROJECT \
      --path=gs://$BUCKET/data/** \
      --stagingLocation=gs://$BUCKET/staging/ \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

Results:

[image]

Full [code](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/f34058bb0811daddf1703084e78e003d)

Let me know how this works. This was just an example to get started and you might need to adjust windowing and triggering strategies, lateness, etc to suit your use case